# How can i possibly make a dynamic REST API link of a Model that changes by id of another Model?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

What i currently have setted up with django rest is :

**MODEL NAME : Animes**

- **/api/** <- root
- **/api/animes/** <- lists all animes available in my db
- **/api/animes/id/** <-  returns the anime instance that has id=id

**MODEL NAME : Episodes**

- **/api/** <- root
- **/api/episodes/** <- lists all episodes of all animes available in my db
- **/api/episodes/id/** <-  returns the episode instance that has id=id

So basically im trying to achieve is :

if i request **api/episodes/{anime_name}/**

i get that specific anime's Episodes listed .

how can i do that ?

**EpisodesSerializer**

```
class EpisodesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model   = Episodes
    fields = '__all__'
```

**Router**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('animes', AnimesViewSet, 'animes')
router.register('episodes', EpisodesViewSet, 'episodes')

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

**EpisodesViewSet**

```
class EpisodesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

   permission_classes  = [permissions.AllowAny]
   MainModel           = Episodes
   queryset            = Episodes.objects.all()
   serializer_class    = EpisodesSerializer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

As the OP mentioned in the comments, the newer versions of DRF use @action instead as @detail_route and @list_route are deprecated.

To use a different field for lookup, you can implement the logic to get the object yourself but you have to make sure that the field you're using for lookup is unique, else you can have many objects returned.

So assuming the anime `name` is unique and you want to use it for lookup, you can do this:

```
@action(detail=True, methods=['get'])
def episodes(self, *args, **kwargs):
    anime = Anime.objects.get(name=self.kwarg[self.lookup_field])
    episodes = Episode.objects.filter(anime=anime)
    ...
```

You can also check how `get_object()` is implemented to make it more robust. 
    I made a generic view mixin for myself that allows lookup with multiple unique fields aprt from the main pk lookup field:

```
class AlternateLookupFieldsMixin(object):
"""
Looks up objects for detail endpoints using alternate
lookup fields assigned in `alternate_lookup_fields` apart
from the default lookup_field. Only unique fields should be used
else Http404 is raised if multiple objects are found
"""

alternate_lookup_fields = []

def get_object(self):
    try:
        return super().get_object()
    except Http404:
        lookup_url_kwarg = self.lookup_url_kwarg or self.lookup_field
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        obj = None
        for lookup_field in self.alternate_lookup_fields:
            filter_kwargs = {lookup_field: self.kwargs[lookup_url_kwarg]}
            try:
                obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, **filter_kwargs)
            except Http404:
                pass
        if obj:
            self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
            return obj
        raise Http404
```

All you have to do is add it to your view's base classes and add the fields for lookup(name in your case) in the `alternate_lookup_fields` attribute. Of course, only use unique fields.

As for filtering, you can check how simple filtering is done [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters).
However, I will recommend using a more generic filter backend like [django-filter](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend)

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

First of all, the url will look more initutive like this:

```
api/anime/<anime_id>/episodes/
```

This is because you should usually start from a more generic resource to more specific ones.

To achieve this, in your AnimeViewSet(not EpisodesViewSet), you can have a detail route for the episodes like this:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import detail_route


@detail_route(methods=['get'])
def episodes(self, *args, **kwargs):
    anime = self.get_object()
    episodes = Episode.objects.filter(anime=anime)
    page = self.paginate_queryset(anime)
    if page is not None:
        serialier = EpisodesSerializer(page, context=self.get_serializer_context(), many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

    serializer = EpisodesSerializer(episodes, context=self.get_serializer_context()) many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

You could also just use a filter on the EpisodesViewSet to fetch episodes belonging to a particular anime this way:

```
api/episodes?anime=<anime_id>
```

Comment: Hello @Ken4scholars Thanks for you great explaination , but im using the last version of django , currently i hear that the detail_route no longer available kind of replace by action i guess !

anyway , i tried your code out only replace the decorator : `@action(methods=['get'],detail=True)`

but when i go to :  http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/animes/name_of_anime/episodes/ it does not work , i believe this works in case if  'id'  !
thats good i mean working with uniq id is cool but i just want to try some stuff later with the name , if thats possible how can i achieve exactly that ?
Thanks !

Comment: I would also like if u point me to somewhere  where i can learn about : api/episodes?anime=<anime_id> , thanks you !

Comment: This is realy Cool ! thanks fr the class realy AMAZING  :D
before seeing your answer i managed to achieve what i needed using this : 
`li = Episodes.objects.all().filter(anime_name=self.kwargs[self.lookup_field])
        result_list =  li.values()
        return Response(result_list)`

Thanks alot man for your detailed answers , very much apreciated .

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, you don't need to call `all()` before `filter()`